# Как проверить позиционные аргументы функции на наличие заданного числа?

Tags: python

Например, вам нужно создать функцию, которая должна принимать произвольное количество позиционных аргументов и возвращать True, если среди аргументов передается заданное число (например 10), в противном случае возвращать False.
Например:

```
def has_10(a, b, c):
   if has_10(a ,b ,c) == 10:
       return True
   return False
```

Где здесь ошибка ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3):

1. Первая ошибка - в описании функции задано не произвольное, а конкретное число аргументов  - три. Для передачи произвольного количества позиционных аргументов нужно использовать оператор * c переменной. Обычно используется `*args`. Можно почитать, например, [здесь](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/3.8.php)
2. Вторая ошибка - в условии `if has_10(a ,b ,c) == 10:`, которое зачем-то рекурсивно вызывает функцию и проверяет результат на равенство 10, хотя функция возвращает только True или False.

```
def has_10(*args):
    return 10 in args

print(has_10(1, 2, 3, 10))
print(has_10(1, 3, 9))
```

```
True
False
```